# How to render multiple child components based on condition one after another in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have three sections in parent component, each section I want to render one child component like componentA in 1st section, componentB in 2nd section and componentC in 3rd section.
Each section should  be rendered one after another based on the condition, after submitting form in each component based on response status.

Comment: welcome to [so]. go through how to create [mcve]

Comment: you can use angualr *ngSwitch or *ngIf directives to do this. BY using those directives you can render your child components

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition1">
...
<\ng-contaner>
```

This will (dynamically) render(and update) anything inside, based on the `condition1` boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

Each child component will render the html based on response status.

```
<div>
  <app-componentA [input]="value1" (outputData)="getData1($event)"
    *ngIf="section1"></app-componentA>

<app-componentB [input]="value2" (outputData)="getData2($event)"
    *ngIf="section2"></app-componentB>

<app-componentC [input]="value3" (outputData)="getData3($event)"
    *ngIf="section3"></app-componentC>
</div>
```